# MySQL CONCAT in WHERE Statement (Multi Tables)

Tags: mysql, sql-like

My problem is pretty simple - at least I hope it is. I am try to join two tables in MySQL and the perform a WHERE statement on a concatenated field to produce a result. Here is the sample query:

```
SELECT a.name, b.company, concat_ws(' ', a.company, b.name) as whole_name  
FROM users as a  
INNER JOIN company as b on a.company_id = b.company_id  
HAVING whole_name LIKE '%IBM John%'  
LIMIT 25
```

This query seems to still be pulling from the name column and will return no results. I've tried this by doing:

```
SELECT a.name, b.company, concat_ws(' ', a.company, b.name) as whole_name  
FROM users as a  
INNER JOIN company as b on a.company_id = b.company_id  
WHERE concat_ws(' ', a.company, b.name) LIKE '%IBM John%'  
LIMIT 25
```

And it still doesn't yield any results. The data is absolutely in the table. The company for John is IBM Computer Systems. The `whole_name` field would return `'IBM Computer Systems John Smith'` but a query on `'%IBM John%'` return nothing.

Any help?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Need a % between IBM and John... it's looking for "IBM John" somewhere in the text... not IBM then John somewhere further along..

Comment: So for each search term, you need to break it up and add an '%' symbol? Such as '%IBM% %John%'?

Comment: % is a wildcard, you can do '%IBM%John%' and it'll do it, if you want to enforce that they are in seperate words then '%IBM% %John%' looks for IBM, then a space somewhere after, and then John somewhere after that. '%IBM%John%' would also match if "IBMJohn" (i.e lack of space) is within the text.